# how to show limited record if it the number of row reach value of specified fields

Tags: mysql, sorting, left-join

as a titled said, is it actually possible to do that ?,
so first i have 
**student**

```
+------------+------- +---------+
| id_student | score_a|score_b  |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 1          | 70     |80       |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 2          | 70     |90       |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 3          | 80     |70       |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 4          | 80     |70       |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 5          | 80     |90       |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 6          | 60     |70       |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 7          | 60     |80       |
+------------+--------+---------+
| 8          |40      |70       |
+------------+--------+---------+
```

then **class**

```
+----------+--------------+
| id_class | limit_people |
+----------+--------------+
| 1        | 1            |
+----------+--------------+
| 2        | 2            |
+----------+--------------+
| 3        | 2            |
+----------+--------------+
```

and register table

**register**

```
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| id_register | id_students | id_class |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| 1           | 1           | 1        |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| 2           | 1           | 2        |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| 3           | 2           | 2        |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| 4           | 2           | 3        |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| 5           | 3           | 1        |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| 6           | 3           | 3        |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| 7           | 4           | 3        |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
| 8           | 4           | 2        |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

is there a way if let's say one of class reach the max limit based on `class.limit_people` field, can't be the records that contain those id_class will not be showed again instead they will be showed with other id_class that they had as well since 1 students can have 2 id_class?
for example : `class.limit_people = 1` for `id_class = 1` , and in the resulted table there's 2 records that using id_class=1 , can't it only be showed only once(the students that have the higher score on `total`?

current query :

```
SELECT 
  register.id_register, 
  register.id_students, 
  (student.score_a + student.score_b)*50/100 AS total,
  register.id_class 
FROM 
  `register` 
LEFT JOIN 
  `student` 
ON (register.id_students = student.id_student)
GROUP BY register.id_students 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

by running on those query , resulted that i had

```
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| id_register | id_students | total | id_class |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 3           | 2           | 80    | 2        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 1           | 1           | 75    | 1        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 5           | 3           | 75    | 1        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 7           | 4           | 75    | 3        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
```

as you can see `id_students = 3` with `id_class=1` are showed on the table instead (max row =1 based on `class.limit_people`), result that i wanted is the one that showed `id_class=3`

```
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| id_register | id_students | total | id_class |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 3           | 2           | 80    | 2        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 1           | 1           | 75    | 1        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 6           | 3           | 75    | 3        | */ id_class = 3 instead of 1 since it's still not reach the max capacity
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
| 7           | 4           | 75    | 3        |
+-------------+-------------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: So you want to show the top n graded students per class, where n = limit_people?

Comment: What if students are tied?

Comment: And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE score >=100 AND ROWNUM <= 3;
```

this is just to answer the question who got the highest score in just showing three rows.

0xb7BA52343f45927B9CEAeaaB16228CA6Eb9FE5a4